# Why isn't the Byte Order Mark emitted from UTF8Encoding.GetBytes?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding, utf-8

The snippet says it all :-)

```
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true/*include Byte Order Mark*/);
byte[] data = enc.GetBytes("a");
// data has length 1.
// I expected the BOM to be included. What's up?
```

Comment: As said below, the BOM isn't necessary for UTF8.

Comment: Saying "the BOM isn't necessary for UTF-8" is simply inaccurate. The preamble is how applications distinguish between UTF8 and codepaged ANSI.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You wouldn't want it to be used for *every* call to GetBytes, otherwise you'd have no way of (say) writing a file a line at a time.

By exposing it with [GetPreamble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getpreamble.aspx), callers can insert the preamble just at the appropriate point (i.e. at the start of their data). I agree that the documentation could be a lot clearer though.

Comment: In general, you should be able to ignore the preamble, since your writer will insert it based on your encoding choice.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you both. The following works, and LINQ makes the combination simple :-)

```
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true);
byte[] data = enc.GetBytes("a");
byte[] combo = enc.GetPreamble().Concat(data).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. Note that `Encoding.UTF8` is a shorthand for `new UTF8Encoding(true)`, so your first line could be just `var enc = Encoding.UTF8;`, or in-line it to the other two, or even shrink the whole thing to a one-liner `var combo = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("a")).ToArray();` Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is expected that `GetBytes()` will be called lots of times... you need to use:

```
byte[] preamble = enc.GetPreamble();
```

(only call it at the start of a sequence) and write that; *this* is where the BOM lives.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in general, you don't need the Byte Order Mark for UTF-8 anyway. It's main purpose is to tell UTF16 BE and UTF16 LE apart. There is no such thing as UTF8 LE and UTF8 BE.

Comment: It also allows you to differentiate UTF-8 files from ANSI files.

Comment: Even Microsoft admits "ANSI" is a confusing name - even when it's used to describe a charset. "ANSI files" don't exist anyway; on Windows all files are binary (Mainframes did have true text files, but they didn't have "Microsoft ANSI")